# Sparsest matrix with specified row and column sums

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

Given a sequence of row sums $r_1, \ldots, r_m$ and column sums $c_1, \ldots, c_n$, all positive, I'd like to find a matrix $A_{m\times n}$ consistent with the given row and column sums that has the fewest nonzero entries. That is, we want to minimize $|\{a_{ij} \ne 0\}|$ under the constraint that $\sum_j a_{ij} = r_i$ and $\sum_i a_{ij} = c_j$.

One can also think of this as a network flow problem, with $m$ sources and $n$ sinks that must be connected with the minimum number of edges to achieve the specified flow out of each source ($r_i$) or into each sink ($c_j$).

Is this a known problem, or does it fit into a well-known class of problems? What is the computational complexity of finding the optimal solution? According to the comments on [this Reddit discussion](http://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/darwh/accounting_help_with_a_dash_of_linear_algebra/), it could be related to the [cutting stock problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem), but it's not exactly the same.

The motivation for this problem comes from settling debts. Suppose you have a set of people $P$ with debts between them. These debts can be settled by (1) finding the net debt $d(p)$ owed to each person $p \in P$, (2) dividing $P$ into two disjoint sets of people who are owed, $P_+ = \{p : d(p) > 0\}$, and people who owe, $P_- = \{p : d(p) < 0\}$, and (3) having the people in $P_-$ pay the ones in $P_+$. Then the problem of resolving debts with the fewest transactions is equivalent to the above optimization problem, with $a_{ij}$ being the amount that the $i$th person in $P_-$ must give the $j$th person in $P_+$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that, as T.. had guessed, the problem is indeed NP-hard. I realised this after participating in some discussions in the comments of [this blog post](http://www.toastandtesla.com/engineering/maths/good-friendship-requires-good-accounting/) where the same problem turned up again, and [the corresponding Reddit discussion](http://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/dioxr/resolving_debts_to_your_friends_with_minimal/c10huhd). The solution I am posting here is based on the above.

First, a lemma: The optimal solution for $m+n$ people cannot have more than $m+n-1$ nonzero entries.

The proof is by inductive construction of a solution with $m+n-1$ entries. For $m = n = 1$, the solution trivially has 1 entry. When $m+n > 2$, let $a_{11} = \min(r_1,c_1)$. This satisfies one row or column (or both, if $r_1 = c_1$), leaving a subproblem of size $m+n-1$ whose solution has at most $m+n-2$ entries. This completes the proof of the lemma.

Suppose a solution exists with fewer than $m+n-1$ entries. Consider the network flow view of the problem, with $m+n$ nodes connected by edges. If there are fewer than $m+n-1$ edges, the underlying undirected graph is disconnected. Then each connected component is "self-sufficient" in that it has no net in- or out-flow. That means that the sum of the corresponding subset of $\{r_i\} \cup \{-c_j\}$ is zero. So, this problem includes the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which is NP-complete.

More precisely, suppose an instance of the subset sum problem is given as a set of integers $X = \{x_1,\ldots,x_k\}$, and the problem is to determine whether there is a nonempty subset of $X$ whose sum is zero. Let these be the debts $d(p)$ among a set of people $P$ as in the question, introducing an additional person with $d(p) = -\sum X$ to balance the books. Then there is a solution with fewer than $|P|-1$ entries if and only if there is a subset of $X$ with sum zero. (The above lemma is useful for proving the "if" part.) Therefore the subset sum problem can be reduced to this problem.

Answer (score 5):

This is linear optimization in the $L_0$ (Hamming) metric which in full generality is NP-hard, so either there is a solution adapted to the specific structure of the debt settlement equations, or it is intractable.

One structure the debt settlement system has is sparsity.  It can be written as $m+n$ equations in $mn$ variables, with only $2mn$ (out of $(mn)^2$) nonzero coefficients. This is a very sparse system to which $L_0$-$L_1$ transference (so-called "compressed sensing") methods may apply, reducing the problem to linear programming.

Comment: Thanks, the connection to compressed sensing is surprising and very interesting. I'm trying to look up the precise conditions under which $L_0$-$L_1$ transference holds, but it occurs to me that if the $L_1$ metric is $\sum a_{ij}$, then it is constant (equal to $\sum r_i$ and $\sum c_j$) over the entire feasible space, so this may not help for this problem.

Comment: Rahul, that's a very interesting observation.  Thanks.